# Why "Hello World" console application uses 4 threads?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Why very simple "Hello World" console application uses 4 threads? Is it because I have 4 core CPU? How can I (or should I) reduce the thread count to 1?

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do the code do?

Comment: Windows dll implementation. I don't think they can be a problem, but I don't know if and how reduce them

Comment: You will get answer only when you show us your code.

Comment: this is system working threads pool

Comment: @RbMm: why 3 threads then? An odd number (no pun intended).

Comment: If you load symbols for those threads via the UI option, you'll see they are 'threadpool' threads waiting for work. Are they getting in your way?

Comment: Depending on what the application does you might not want to do that. Please define that "very simple console application", or post the source code.

Comment: Just prints "Hello World". :)

Comment: @MikeVine: what are those threads for? Why 3 pool threads and not 4?

Comment: @Narek Using what.. MFC, Win32, std::cout?

Comment: They're just an implementation detail on how windows app works. If you've got an actual problem with them (and also understand why you want to get rid of them) I'm sure someone will help you.

Comment: Confirmed with MSVC 2015 (v140 runtime) http://i.imgur.com/Cs77037.png?1

Comment: If you are really curious, get proper symbols and look at the stack traces of the threads. That may shed some light on what they are used for / doing.

Comment: @Christian.K I think it is a duplicate, but could someone explain what thread pool we talk about and what .dlls when it is just a "Hello World". Why we need .dlls?

Comment: I don't understand. There are many DLLs being linked to your process by default (some of which may do nasty things in their dllmain function - albeit maybe not the case here). IOW there is a lot more going on in your process then your main function (c runtime initializing as another example). And the default Windows thread pool is meant.